# but i am facing an error on travis for singed apk generation

Tags: android

i am facing an error on travis for singed apk generation.
i am using windows 10 for encrypting .jks file

### but i am facing an error on travis.

0.02s$ openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_463e675557ea_key -iv $encrypted_463e675557ea_iv -in raptor_keystore.jks.enc -out raptor_keystore.jks -d
1810bad decrypt
1811139632825865888:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
1812The command "openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_463e675557ea_key -iv $encrypted_463e675557ea_iv -in raptor_keystore_keystore.jks.enc -out raptor_keystore_keystore.jks -d" failed and exited with 1 during .

Comment: This issue has been resolved... for this travis-ci does not support Windows for generation of enc file  for android jks file currently  it only supporting on Linux and Mac system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved... 
For this travis-ci does not support Windows for generation of enc file for android jks file currently it only supporting on Linux and Mac system.